# Create Element with id or class with React Dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

I am creating an element like so

```
const foo = document.createElement('div');
ReactDOM.render(component, foo);
```

I wonder if it is possible to create `foo` with an `class` or `id`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `id` and/or `class` of `foo` can be specified via the [`setAttribute(..)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) and [`classList.add(..)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Methods) methods as shown:

```
const foo = document.createElement('div');

/* Set id of "some-id" on foo */
foo.setAttribute("id", "some-id");

/* Add class of "some-class" to foo */
foo.classList.add("some-class");
```

Answer (score 14):

I would suggest you create it in a proper React way:

```
const App = () => {
  return React.createElement(
    "div",
    {style:{color:"red"}, id: 'someId', className: "someClass"},
    "Here I am",
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(App), document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: would it be `class: "someClass"` or `className: "someClass"`?

Comment: asking because I believe `class` may be a reserved word.

Comment: You are right - className... I just checked it now in jsfiddle and there were no errors in console and if you inspect it, everything is parsed as it should be https://jsfiddle.net/Lazzaro83/wr4x08sz/